# Sidekiq no dead jobs were found

Tags: sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

I create sidekiq worker as following and exec it

```
require 'sidekiq'

class HardWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options :queue => 'crawler'

    def perform(name, count)
        logger.info "#{name}: #{count}"
        puts 'Doing hard work'
        puts 1/0
    end
end
```

And then, and enqueue job by running this code :

```
Sidekiq::Client.push({'class' => 'HardWorker', 'queue' => 'crawler', 'args' => ['name 1', 1], 'retry' => 1})
```

Of course, sidekiq worker will throw exception because of 1/0 . But after one retry, I don't see this job in dead job of sidekiq web ui.

So can anybody explain me or provide any idea for this.

Thanks

Comment: From the wiki: [best practices](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#best-practices)
    

  Sidekiq will move the job to the dead queue after trying to run it for 25 times. Not before that.

Comment: Vinay, Sidekiq will move it to the DJQ when retries are exhausted.  He's clearly configuring it to use 1 retry only.

Comment: What does the sidekiq log say?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Did not see the push arguments

Comment: thanks @MikePerham , by looking errors in log file, I searched correct issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In log file, I found this line :

```
uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::RetryJobs::DeadSet
```

And then , I google and go to link https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1915

So, I did as mperham guide by adding

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
```

It worked correctly, failed jobs appeared in dead jobs queue

Answer (score 0):

Just a better way of doing stuff with sidekiq, not sure if this will solve the problem, but this is worth a try
**hard_worker.rb**

```
require 'sidekiq'
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'crawler', retry: 1

  def perform(name, count)
    logger.info "#{name}: #{count}"
    puts 'Doing hard work'
    puts 1/0
  end
end
```

To enqueue the job
HardWorker.peform_async('name 1', 1)

For more information please refer https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling